# .NET MVC 4 Doesn't Locate view folder correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 4 site and under the Views folder I have my folder for the various views.  One of which is names "services".  Under the controllers I have the services controller.  Everything was jugging along fine.  I then created a folder named "Services" in the root of the site. Now when the routing uses that folder to look for a view rather than looking under in the Views folder.  ????  Can anyone give me insight into this phenom?  I simply renamed the 2nd folder and life is good again but that was unexpected as I thought the routing went to the views folder by default.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a `Services` folder at root. That tells the routing to ignore and not call ASP.NET MVC.

You should have a `Views/Services` folder.

Comment: I believe you're incorrect - it depends on whether or not [RouteCollection.RouteExistingFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.routeexistingfiles.aspx) is set to true in the Global.asax.cs file and whether their route matches the file path at all.

Answer (score -1):

It is likely that your route was something like /Services/MethodName and your view folder was also /Services/MethodName.ascx or whatever on disk... And if you don't tell MVC to route existing files it will let them be served off the disk by default instead. To override this, set [RouteCollection.RouteExistingFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.routeexistingfiles.aspx) = true in Global.asax.cs on Application_Start

This is the disassembled code for finding Views from the default view engines in MVC3:

Razor:

```
public RazorViewEngine(IViewPageActivator viewPageActivator) : base(viewPageActivator)
{
    base.AreaViewLocationFormats = new string[]
    {
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
    };
    base.AreaMasterLocationFormats = new string[]
    {
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
    };
    base.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = new string[]
    {
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
    };
    base.ViewLocationFormats = new string[]
    {
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
    };
    base.MasterLocationFormats = new string[]
    {
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
    };
    base.PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[]
    {
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
    };
    base.FileExtensions = new string[]
    {
        "cshtml",
        "vbhtml"
    };
}
```

WebForms:

```
public WebFormViewEngine(IViewPageActivator viewPageActivator) : base(viewPageActivator)
{
    base.MasterLocationFormats = new string[]
    {
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.master",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.master"
    };
    base.AreaMasterLocationFormats = new string[]
    {
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.master",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.master"
    };
    base.ViewLocationFormats = new string[]
    {
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx"
    };
    base.AreaViewLocationFormats = new string[]
    {
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx"
    };
    base.PartialViewLocationFormats = base.ViewLocationFormats;
    base.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = base.AreaViewLocationFormats;
    base.FileExtensions = new string[]
    {
        "aspx",
        "ascx",
        "master"
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I haven't had time  investigate further.  When I did add the folder I did have a method class inside of it but it was not a controller or a view.  It caught me by surprise that MVC defaulted to the  Services folder in the root and skipped the Services folder in  Views.

Answer (score -1):

You can configure routing in App_Start folder, in the RouteConfig file. If you add

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "", 
            url: "Services/Index/{id}", 
            defaults: new
                          {
                              controller = "Services", 
                              action = "Index", 
                              id = UrlParameter.Optional
                          });
```

beyond routes.IgnoreRoute line, you'll be able to have Services folder in your MVC project, and Services controller with its views.

If you now have in one of your other views something like that:

```
@Html.ActionLink("To services", "Index", "Services")
```

it will now be rendered as ~/Services/Index not just ~/Services

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.